# Java irc library

Tags: java, irc

I'm creating an Swing GUI, I want to include a irc client into the JFrame. So I'm looking for a library that I could easily set up and put in a JPanel. But all I can seem to find on google are applets which run in your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had success using this to build an IRC bot: http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php

I has the libraries used for just IRC as well.

Comment: I'm looking for something that has a UI already, I've looked into pircbot a little but it didn't have that, I believe?

Comment: I recommend against PircBot. It has unfortunate API design which your app will quickly grow from. Rather JawaBot or PircBotX.

Answer (score 8):

There's an IDEA plugin. IDEA is a pure Swing application, so it might be close.

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1175

Other than that, try this list:

- **[SilverTrout](http://code.google.com/p/silvertrout/)** has [many, but simple plugins](http://code.google.com/p/silvertrout/source/browse/#git%2Fsource%2Fsilvertrout%2Fplugins%2Fadminboy). Similar approach as PircBot, only pluggable.
- **[IRClib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/moepii/)**
- **[IRC-API](http://code.google.com/p/irc-api/)** - I haven't tried. Seems to be quite well designed, but I haven't found any how-to.
- **[PircBot](http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php)** is the most famous and probably most used, but suffers from hevay design misconceptions and uses several antipatterns. Only use for really simple bots.
- **[PircBot'](https://github.com/davidlazar/PircBot)** is a PircBot revival by David Lazar, adds some features, mainly SSL.
- **[PircBot 1.7](https://github.com/OndraZizka/PircBot) by me. **Mavenized**. I've partly got rid of the God-object antipattern and changed logging to Slf4j / Log4j, plus some minor additions.
- **[PircBotX](https://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/wiki/)** is a re-implementation of PircBot.
- **[JawaBot 2.x](http://code.google.com/p/jawabot/)** is a pluggable standalone application with IRC and web UI which aims to put multiple functionalities under one bot, while still keeping the structure of the code sane. **Mavenized**.
  Currently, there are few plugins:

  - Jira - resolves name, status and assignee from a Jira issue tracker. Configurable. Default config supports opensource repos: JBoss, Codehaus, Apache and others.
  - Logger - logs IRC events to a DB. Has a web UI.
  - Reservation - for reservation of resources over IRC. Has a web UI.
  - WhereIs - looks for nicks in all channels, supports wildcards.
  - Messenger - delivers messages to users which are offline when they connect ("answering machine").
  - PasteBin - let's user paste text through PM, saves it, and posts a link to a web UI to the channel.
  - AutoOp - gives op to users.
  - Social - reacts to "Hi!" etc. Kind of [Hello World plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jawabot/wiki/HowToWriteIrcPlugin).

Comment: This also exists:

https://github.com/sorcix/sIRC

Answer (score 0):

I am making an Android client, so I needed an IRC library, I didn't like any of the libs, so I made my own library, it's called **BlueIRC**, it's free an open source

[Link to Github](https://github.com/MicroDroid/blueirc/), check out the development branch, JAR builds in *build* folder